# Where does the term "heads or tails" come from?

Tags: etymology

I recently obtained a Silver Angel collectable coin, where the back side bears an image of an angel fighting a dragon: [image: silver angel coin]

I sort of realized, as I was looking at it, that for probably the first time in my life, I was holding a coin where the image on the back *actually portrays a creature with a tail prominently displayed.*

Everyone's heard of "heads or tails?", the traditional invocation for a coin toss.  The head is obvious: most government-issued coins, from antiquity to modern times, have borne the bust of some famous ruler on one side.  But most coins do not come with some tailed animal on the back, so where does the ubiquitous expression come from?

Comment: I think the head is obviously the frequently featured famous person's head.  And, the tail is just the opposite of that.

Comment: @DavidM I agree with you, but I'd also be interested to see if anyone can provide any evidence as to why it's "tails" over "heels", "feet", "back of head", etc.

Comment: Interestingly, the first English angel coin had the angel and dragon on one side (so, "tails") but a ship on the other (so, not "heads") http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel_(coin). Among farthings, at least, there was no coin with both a headed and a tailed entity up to the time of the first recorded usage of "tails" as per Susan's answer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farthing_(English_coin). "tail" meaning "backside of a person, buttocks" is recorded from c.1300,  which supports its use as opposite of "head" http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=tail&allowed_in_frame=0.

Comment: @nxx - but feet are often used as the opposite as well. We talk about someone going *head over **heels*** and the *head* and ***foot*** of the table.

Comment: Many British coins have had less obvious "tails" on the obverse for a long time: George and Dragon on sovereigns, and endless heraldic lions on most silver coins. Equally interesting is why it's plurals: Surely "head or tail" makes more sense, unless it came about during William and Mary's reign...?

Comment: @starsplusplus Indeed. Just a comment based on what answerer's have been saying.

Comment: @Roddy Did any of them that you know of have a headed thing on one side and a tailed thing on the other prior to the 1680s? (which seems to be first recorded usage for "tails" = "reverse side of a coin")

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do we use the plural "heads" and "tails" when describing sides of a coin?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53381/why-do-we-use-the-plural-heads-and-tails-when-describing-sides-of-a-coin) Note that answers to the earlier question do address this question as well. It's not just a question about the plural form.

Answer (score 17):

I don't think **tails** has anything directly to do with what is on the other side of the coin, but rather it is an expression of opposites: the head is at one end of spinal column, the tail at the other (think 'dog' nose to tail are opposites, rather than head and feet). The expression *can't make head nor tail of it* expresses this concept of opposites, and may be where *heads or tails* comes from.

The first recorded use of ["tails"](http://articles.courant.com/2009-06-26/news/words0626.art_1_tails-coin-heads) to mean the reverse side of a coin occurred in a 1684 comedy, "The Atheist," by playwright Thomas Otway. A character in the play advises someone, "As Boys do with their Farthings ... go to Heads or Tails for 'em."

As far as the coin toss goes, it is far from recent. **Cross and pile** was played in England for many centuries. The cross was the major design element on one side of many coins, and the pile was the bottom part of the die used to cast the 'cross' side of the coin. [Brewer's](http://www.bartleby.com/81/4384.html) Dictionary of Phrase and Fable (1898) Samuel Butler used the phrase in the 1600s: “Whacum had neither cross nor pile.” (Butler: Hudibras, part ii. 3.)

Before that, it was done by the Romans, and was called **navia aut caput** ("ship or head"), as some coins had a ship on one side and the head of the emperor on the other.

Comment: +1. More generally, *tail* as the opposite of *head* is found prior to that, in several pairings of the Latin *caput* and *cauda*, such as *caput draconis* and *cauda draconis* (literally "dragon's head" and "dragon's tail") for the lunar nodes. To find *tail* coming into use here is not a surprise.

Comment: Interestingly, most Farthings from the 1600's that I've seen had neither a tail *nor* a head pictured on them.  Mostly buildings and crests.

Comment: Interestingly, in Australia, kids learn the names because the $1 coin has Kangaroos (with their tails) on the Queenless side.

Answer (score 6):

Some of the earliest known coins were found in the ruins of of Lydia in modern-day Turkey. These coins date back to 600 BC, and were engraved with the image of a symbolic animal.

The "obverse" of these coins was usually the head of the animal (or the full animal), such as the famous [Lion-head coin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aBMC_06.jpg). This could explain where the etymology of "heads" and "tails" (as the "back" of the coin could be considered the "tail" of the animal.)

The more obvious answer would be that the terminology started with the Romans and Greeks, since they used heads of states to adorn their coins with (as well as Gods, such as the head of Athena coin). But I wouldn't know where the "tail" terminology comes from in that case.

It's worth noting that our knowledge of the Lydians being among the first cultures to produce coins comes mainly from the Greek historian, Herodotus. So it's likely that the Greens and Romans were inspired by the designs of the Lydians.

[More information on the terminology used in other languages for the obverse and reverse of a coin.](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=633425) And according to Merriam-Webster, the origin of the term "tails" for the reverse of a coin in English dates to 1680.

Comment: I believe tails is just the opposite of heads.  But, the heads is exactly as you've described.

Comment: @DavidM - if that is true why is there so much variation in the term when I travel?

Comment: @RyeBread Can you give an example?  I would guess it depends upon what's on your coins . . . If there is always a frog on one side and monkey on the other, you'd probably say "frogs or monkeys."

Comment: @DavidM - Look at Mason's comment under my answer.  Also how about Roman example.  And in Japan I think they say Head or Words.

Comment: @RyeBread Your answer doesn't obviate my comment.  Rather, it shows that it in fact depends upon what was on the other side.  In countries where the cross was commonly on the obverse, you would say crosses.  As to Mason, well he's from Argentina.  Argentina's Spanish is very heavily influenced by Italian.  (In fact many other Spanish speakers swear their accents are Italian!)

Comment: @RyeBread America has never had a consistent obverse for coins.  And, the expressions can easily evolve independently from one another, or diverge for that matter.

Answer (score 6):

The term is heads or tails in America or Britain but it differs in other countries based on their monetary history.  I know that Italy has Heads or Crosses and back in the Roman days there was Heads or Ships.   Heads is a given.  Most coins have a picture of a leader or powerful figure on one side and the opposite side whatever.

In the US we did have a Buffalo nickel that had a tail on the back but I am sure that the phrase was muttered before that nickel.  It is just that tail is the opposite of head.  The phrase "I can't make head nor tail of it" has nothing to do with coins (I think).

So the phrase is more about the actual money than just making up a phrase to play a game.  And in your picture is a big dragon's tail.

Comment: What's at the caudal end of an eagle if not a tail? The eagle appears on the 1794 silver dollar.

Comment: *What's at the caudal end of an eagle if not a tail?* -- tail feathers.

Comment: Heads or crosses in Italy?  Interesting.  When I lived in Argentina for a while, the coin-toss phrase was *cara o cruz?* (Face or cross?)  Argentine coins, despite the strong Catholic influence on their culture, do not feature crosses on the back.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Argentina, I think you'd agree, has a STRONG Italian influence on its language and culture.  (Up to 60% of the population has Italian ancestry:  [Source Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_Argentine)

Comment: @DavidM: Yeah, that was very noticeable.

Comment: Good point! In Germany we use "Kopf oder Zahl?"

Answer (score 1):

Growing up in Canada, this seemed a very natural expression, as most of our coins have animals on them. A beaver, caribou, loon, and polar bear adorn our five cent, twenty-five cent, one dollar, and two dollar coins, respectively.
[image: Canadian Coins]

Many other countrys, such as Madagascar and Australia also have animals on the back of their coins.

Comment: The two dollar coin is of course the rudest Canadian coin, as it shows the Queen with a bear behind.

Comment: However, to numisma...., er, coin people the "head" (obverse) is the side with the year stamped on it.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia says that "head and tail" might be connected with German Kopf und Zahl (Head and number). In English the word family connected with German Zahl and zählen is to tell, tale, teller (in a bank). But there was a semantic shift in the meaning from to count to narrate.

If Wikipedia's view is right then we have a typical case of transformation.
An old word (Old English talu) that came out of use was changed to another, well-known word: tail. So the coin got a tail, though coins have no tail as everybody knows and you have to search a long time till you find an animal with a tail on the backside.
But almost all coins have the value on the back in large digits (the number or German die Zahl; Modern High German z /ts/ comes from t; in Low German it is still t).

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_flipping#History

Comment: That theory was [removed from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Coin_flipping&type=revision&diff=677752068&oldid=676449240) in 2015 due to missing citations. However the new theory *»heads and tails being considered opposite«* is also a missing a citation.

Answer (score -1):

Two persons decided to go for a horse ride. But who will ride first? The horse was in stable. They decided to work out the solution with a chance. As they enter the stable, is the "head" of the horse facing us or is the "tail" of the horse facing us?. So, one called "Heads" and the other automatically settled for "Tails". This is how they decided who will ride the horse first - a chance with two equally likely probabilities. Does this initiate the history of the terms "heads or tails"?

Comment: Interesting.  Do you have any references for this story?