# Why do we pluralize 'heads' on a coin flip?

Tags: etymology

I've seen a question here about the origin of [**heads or tails**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154584/where-does-the-term-heads-or-tails-come-from) but no explanation of why they're plural. If coins were black- and white-sided I doubt we'd be asked to call 'blacks or whites' on a coin flip. Is there a known reason for this? Or some interesting speculation? (-:

Comment: On top of that there  is the expression “make head or tail of something” used in the singular form in BrE https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/make_head_or_tail_of

Comment: Dang. I did search for dupes but missed that one.